# SSRS - Expand/collapse in the same cell

Tags: reporting-services, expand, ssrs-tablix

I would like to be able to expand/collapse in the same cell as the header in an SSRS tablix.  I do not want to expand to a value that is pulled from a table but static text instead.  Is this possible?

**For Example:** lets say I have 123 in the returned value set for count of total providers.  I want to be able to put in an expand button (+) for the header so I can see how 123 came about.  In my case it will be the query that was used to get 123.  The next row down will be count of claims, etc...

**Initial**

(+) Count of Providers:        123

(+) Count of Claims:           456

**Expanded**
(-) Count of Providers:        123

Select count(*) from providers

(+) Count of Claims:           456

Comment: Thank Daniel, this worked.  However, I have a grouping in the 3rd column so I had to follow the same steps in the 1st 2 columns instead of the whole row.  The only concern, albeit minor, is when the report is run and it is viewed in the browser there is a blank/empty row.  Is there a resolution for this?  It works when exporting to Excel though.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a non-grouped row to your tablix which will be hidden and contain the count formula to be toggled.

Assuming that the query definition isn't coming from the query itself (although it could be easily modified to do that...), I started with a report designer like this.  No groups, just the count pulled into the first and third rows:

[image]

Rows two and four need their initial visibility set to hidden and a toggle set to the appropriate textbox that contains the aggregate count:
[image]

Which should result in this.

**Initial**:

[image]

**Expanded**:

[image]

*Note that if you are using a dataset with multiple rows and therefore have groups in your tablix, you will have to alter the example accordingly.*